# Text User Interface (TUI) in VSCode not displayed when debugging bash script

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, tui

I am using VS Code for remote SSH bash development. The script uses the Dialog app to create a Text User Interface (TUI) interface

If I open an integrated terminal (in VS Code) and run the bash script from the command line, the TUI is displayed in the terminal

[image]

However, if I use the debugger and run the script, when I reach the code associated with the TUI, the TUI is not displayed and the debug console keeps printing the error below:

```
cannot open tty-output
TIMEOUT SCANNING
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the answer was in plain sight. It was in the github 'Read Me' file [VS Code Bash Debugger Extension](https://github.com/rogalmic/vscode-bash-debug)

When I installed the extension from within VS Code, I did not read all the way down.

[image]